# How can I access to derived members from a pure virtual base class function?

Tags: c++, templates, interface, polymorphism

I want to have a Collider interface class in which will have a  overloaded -> operator to have access directy to the BoxCollider derived class. I want to have access to the members of box collider through the interface and chnage the type of collider at run-time. 
So I thought of using templates:

```
template<typename T>
class ColliderV2 {
public:
    virtual T* operator ->() = 0;
};

class BoxColliderV2 : public ColliderV2<BoxColliderV2> {
public:
    float width;
    float height;

    BoxColliderV2* operator ->() {
        return this;
    }


};
int main()
{
    ColliderV2<BoxColliderV2>* col = new BoxColliderV2;
    (*col)->width = 1; 

}
```

This works. But templates , as far as  I know, will generate a brand new Collider class in compile-time filling T with Box Collider, correct? Thats why it worked. But later it prevents me from changing the collider type. I also thought of just making a virtual Collider class with `Collider* operator->() ;` overload in the derived class `BoxCollider* operator->() ;`

But if I tried :

```
Collider<BoxCollider>* col = new BoxCollider;
(*col)->width = 1; // won't work
```

doesn't work since Collider is not BoxCollider. And I don't want to dynamic_cast every possible collider type I could have. So, what can be done here?

Comment: Please be careful with and correct the type names in your example code.  As it stands the working and non-working examples are both exactly the same ( as far as I can see).

Comment: Yes, the last example should be `Collider<BoxCollider>* col = new BoxCollider;`. Typo. Correcting it right now.

Comment: Is the `V2` significant to your question?

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt not really, I was just creating some classes and testing one and another at the same time. So, inr order to not have class with the same name, I added V2 at the name's end. But I forgot to remove when asking the question.

Comment: How do you expect to know, at the time you make the `(*col)->width = 1;` assignment, that `*col` is a (dynamic) type that has a `width` member?  Somewhere, somehow you need to make that determination, and when you do that it may provide a clue to the necessary solution.

Comment: Just a note: Your code looks like the Couriously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP). Basically, your baseclass knows its derived class which it receives via the template parameter. For that reason, you could also implement `operator->` (Note: This adds another level of complexity when dealing with issues, so a plain memberfunction would be better) using `return static_cast<T*>(this)`, without any pure virtual stuff.

Answer (score 2):

As you've already found out, this doesn't work. Templates and runtime behavior are kind of contradicting mechanics. You can't create a common base class and let it act like a generic pointer to give you access to its derived types' members.

An interface specifies a contract against which you can code. You don't code against a specific implementation but the interface, so the interface has to provide all the members that you'd like to access. In your case this would result in `width` and `height` beeing part of `ColliderV2` instead of `BoxColliderV2`. However this defeates the logic you are trying to mimic.

There are a few approaches that you can take:

1. Either make your collider type a variant, like

   ```
   using ColliderType = std::variant<BoxColliderV2, MyOtherCollider, ...>;
   ```

   and check for the actual type when you want to access the member

   ```
   ColliderType myCollider = /* generate */;

   if (auto boxCollider = std::get_if<BoxColliderV2>(&myCollider); boxCollider)
       boxCollider->width = 0;
   ```
2. Or, keep the base class that you have, remove the `operator->` and the template and do a dynamic cast on it:

   ```
   ColliderV2* col = new BoxColliderV2;
   if (auto boxCollider = dynamic_cast<BoxColliderV2*>(col); boxCollider)
       boxCollider->width = 0;
   ```
3. You can also hide details like `width` or `height` behind more generic functions that are part of the interface. For example:

   ```
   class ColliderV2 {
   public:
       virtual void setBounds(float width, float height) = 0;
   };

   class BoxColliderV2 : public ColliderV2 {
   public:
       void setBounds(float width, float height) override {
           this->width = width;
           this->height = height;
       }

   private:
       float width;
       float height;
   };

   int main()
   {
       ColliderV2* col = new BoxColliderV2;
       col->setBounds(1, 1); 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are approaching the problem from the wrong direction. The purpose of an interface is that you don't have to know about the exact type or the implementation.

For example: You are using Axis-Aligned Bounding Boxes for collision detection. So, even if your `CircleCollider` uses a `radius`, you are still able to calculate its `width` and `height` from it. Now, you don't have to worry about if you are dealing with a `BoxCollider` or a `CircleCollider`, you have everything to make a Bounding Box.

```
class Collider
{
public:
    virtual float x() const = 0;
    virtual float y() const = 0;
    virtual float width() const = 0;
    virtual float height() const = 0;
};

class BoxCollider : public Collider
{
    // Implementation...
};

class CircleCollider : public Collider
{
    // Implementation...
};
```

Of course, you are maybe using something else, and not AABBs. I just wanted to demonstrate how you can use interfaces effectively.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is discouraged by C++. What you are trying to do is to change the type of something based on the return value of a function. The type system is *designed* to stop you from writing code like this.
One important restriction of a function is that can only return one type-of-thing.  You can return one of a list of things if you wrap those possibilities in a class, and return that. In C++17, a ready-made class for this is [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). The restriction on this is that the list of things must be fixed (or a closed-set). If you want an arbitrary set of return values (open-set), you must use a different approach. You must restate your problem in terms a function that is done on the return value.

```
class BoxColliderV2 : public MyBaseCollider {
public:
    void SetWidth(float new_width) override; 
};
```

You may find this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_ij0YNkFUs) useful. The bit of interest starts at around 40 minutes (but watch the whole video if you can). If you are interested in advice, I would suggest starting with [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), and if it works, move to virtual functions. Problems like collision detection get really complicated really quickly, and you will almost certainly require [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) at some stage. Start simple, because it's only going to get more complicated.

These excerpts from the ISO-Guidelines may help
 1. When you change the semantic meaning of an operator, you make it
    harder for other programmers to understand you code. [guideline](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c160-define-operators-primarily-to-mimic-conventional-usage).
 2. Dynamic casting is verbose and ugly, but deliberately so, because dynamic casting is dangerous, and should stand out. [guideline](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c146-use-dynamic_cast-where-class-hierarchy-navigation-is-unavoidable)